# Adjoint Representation of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: representation-theory

The following is taken directly from [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SL2(R)#Adjoint_representation) on $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$:

> **Adjoint representation**
>
> The group $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ acts on its Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$ by conjugation (remember that the Lie algebra elements are also 2 by 2 matrices), yielding a faithful 3-dimensional linear representation of PSL(2,R). This can alternatively be described as the action of PSL(2,R) on the space of quadratic forms on R2. The result is the following representation:
>
> $$\begin{pmatrix}
>   a & b \\
>   c & d \\
> \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}
>   a^2 & 2ac & c^2 \\
>   ab & ac+bd & cd \\
>   b^2 & 2bd & d^2 \\
> \end{pmatrix}.$$

So my question is ... could somebody please explain to me what is going on here? How does the conjugation of $2 \times 2$ matrices result in a $3 \times 3$ matrix?

Feel free to assume I'm very stupid in your answer - I've tried to understand representation theory, but it all seems very obscure to me!

Thanks :)

Comment: Because $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$ is a three-dimensional real vector space

Comment: Is that just because it has three basis matrices (ok, I feel a bit stupid at missing that)? How do you get a $3 \times 3$ matrix from the $2 \times 2$ basis matrices?

Comment: I can see your confusion. The Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$ is a three dimensional vector space. The representation takes each element of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ and outputs a linear map $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)\to\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb R)$. This linear map, being an endomorphism of a three-dimensional vector space, can be represented by a $3\times 3$ matrix. If you pick the standard basis, and explicitly compute the action of $\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb R)$ on it, the result will pop out.

Comment: Warning:  This formula sends the identity matrix to a matrix whose second row is all zeros!